# I am trying to get the results page to display the database information based on what is in the form fields

Tags: php, mysql, database

I need to work the bugs out using a form to query a databse. I followed a tutorial and it looks to have a few bugs

http://bite-hard.com/pitmatch/pm.html

I cant seem to get the results to display

Form:

```
<form name="form1" method="get" action="results.php">
<table width="300" border="0">
<tr>
<td width="130">Age</td>
<td width="170"><input name="name" type="text" id="name" value= "<?php echo $_GET['name'] ?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>State</td>
<td><select name="location" id="location">
<option>Select</option>
<option value="Co">Co</option>
<option value="Fl">Fl</option>
<option value="Il">Il</option>

</select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>City</td>
<td><input name="city" type="text" id="city"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Results Page:

```
<?
$hostname = "localhost"; // Our DB server.
$username = "bitehard_gdub"; // The username you created for this database.
$password = "reakwon"; // The password you created for the username.
$usertable = "dogs"; // The name of the table you made.
$dbName = "bitehard_pitmatch"; // This is the name of the database you made.
 //if there is a search term
if(isset($_GET['name']) && !empty($_GET['name']))
{

//REMEMBER TO CONNECT TO DATABASE!

mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("$dbName") or die(mysql_error());

//**EDIT TO YOUR TABLE NAME, ECT.

$t = mysql_query("SELECT city, state, age FROM dogs WHERE name LIKE '%" .       $_GET['name'] . "%'");
if(!$t) die(mysql_error());

$a = mysql_fetch_object($t);
$total_items = mysql_num_rows($t);
$limit = $_GET['limit'];
$type = $_GET['type'];
$page = $_GET['page'];
$name = urlencode($_GET['name']);

//set default if: $limit is empty, non numerical, less than 10, greater than 50
if((!$limit) || (is_numeric($limit) == false) || ($limit < 10) || ($limit > 50)) {
$limit = 10; //default
}
//set default if: $page is empty, non numerical, less than zero, greater than total    available
if((!$page) || (is_numeric($page) == false) || ($page < 0) || ($page > $total_items)) {
$page = 1; //default
}

//calcuate total pages
$total_pages = ceil($total_items / $limit);
$set_limit = $page * $limit - ($limit);
echo $limit;
//query: **EDIT TO YOUR TABLE NAME, ECT.

$q = mysql_query("SELECT city, state, age FROM dogs WHERE name LIKE '%" .  $_GET['name'] . "%' LIMIT $set_limit, $limit");
if(!$q) die(mysql_error());
 $err = mysql_num_rows($q);
 if($err == 0) die("No matches met your criteria.");

 //Results per page: **EDIT LINK PATH**
 echo("
 <a href=search10.php?cat=$cat&amp;limit=10&amp;page=1&amp;name=".$name.">10</a> |
 <a href=search10.php?cat=$cat&amp;limit=25&amp;page=1&amp;name=".$name.">25</a> |
 <a href=search10.php?cat=$cat&amp;limit=50&amp;page=1&amp;name=".$name.">50</a>");

 //show data matching query:
 while($code = mysql_fetch_object($q)) {
 echo("<BR>");
 echo("<BR>");
 echo("name: ".$code->Age."<BR>");
 echo("city: ".$code->city."<BR>");
 echo("state: ".$code->state."<BR>");
 }


 $cat = urlencode($cat); //makes browser friendly

 //prev. page: **EDIT LINK PATH**

 $prev_page = $page - 1;

 if($prev_page >= 1) {
 echo("<b>&lt;&lt;</b> <a href=search10.php?cat=$cat&amp;limit=$limit& amp;page=$prev_page&amp;name=".$name."><b>Prev.</b></a>");
 }

 //Display middle pages: **EDIT LINK PATH**

 for($a = 1; $a <= $total_pages; $a++)
 {
 if($a == $page) {
  echo("<b> $a</b> | "); //no link
 } else {
 echo(" <a href=search10.php?cat=$cat&amp;limit=$limit&amp;page=$a&amp;name=".$name.">  $a </a> | ");
 }
 }

 //next page: **EDIT THIS LINK PATH**

  $next_page = $page + 1;
  if($next_page <= $total_pages) {
  echo("<a href=search10.php?cat=$cat&amp;limit=$limit&amp;page=$next_page&        amp;name=".$name."><b>Next</b></a> &gt; &gt;");
  }

  }//end of the if statement

  //all done ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, you can't use $_GET[''] in your HTML form.

```
<td width="170"><input name="name" type="text" id="name" value= "<?php echo $_GET['name'] ?>"></td>
```

$_GET is only relevant once the 'submit' button has been selected and results.php is run. This is why your field value displays: "?php echo $_GET['name'] ?"

To connect to the database, try a syntax more like this:

```
$con = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);

if (!$con){die('Could not connect:' . mysql_error());}

mysql_select_db($dbName, $con);
```

Have a look through the basic syntax there - curly brackets { & } are missing from a lot of your sample code - especially around the IF statements. [Check the PHP manual on these.](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php)

You also may want to enclose your next part in an 'else' statement:

```
if(!$t){die(mysql_error());}
else { $a....etc }
```

I also can't see any fields with the name 'limit', 'type' or 'page' - so I'm not sure where you're hoping these results will be obtained from.

There's quite a lot more to go through, so I'll leave it at that for now - have a read through other questions relating to mysql_query() and see if you can find some of the answers.

Final bit which puzzled me: you test in an IF statement whether a number is numeric using:

```
...is_numeric($limit) == false || ($page < 0)...
```

You are testing for a variable not to be a number, but then test to see if it's smaller than zero - surely you would want is_numeric($limit) == true?

Let me know how my suggestions work out and whether you find the answers you need elsewhere.

Comment: It seems to be working now but instead of displaying the specific profile I am looking for its displaying all 3.

Comment: If you edit your original question to display your updated code, I'll have a look at that. Finding it hard to decipher what you want from the original post.